# exception propogation from jersey class

Tags: jax-rs

Could some one give me some pointers as to how do i propogate an exception from jersey class to lets say a JSP, along with some examples if possible..

Thanks in advance
Adhir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Runtime exception to propogate the exception.. WebApplicationException in the JSR311 api does the same thing for you.. if the client is a web app.

Otherwise a checked exception would suffice

Comment: I did this, but something seems to gobble up the exception. In my configured error handler jsp, the exception variable is null.